# How to play large no. Of GIF images in WPF, C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need some help in Making a slideshow type application in WPF. Problem is, Image that needs to be used in this application are .gif, for which i think so we dont have any control in WPF.

Does any one have any idea of how to play those images without impacting any kind of performance? Also the machine in which i need to use this application is windows XP, that means the we can only use up to .net 4.0.

What I have tried:

I have tried many examples find over this page, but the memory it consumes is too high as i need to change image more often.
Dll's that i have tried are

wpfanimatedgif:- It has some serious memory leak issues.

also i have tried

XamlAnimatedGif:- it works fine while running on .net 4.5 machine. but was unable to display any image while on .net 4.0 machine.

Comment: I haven't tried it but there is a Gif Decoder see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.gifbitmapdecoder(v=vs.110).aspx and https://daran9.wordpress.com/2009/12/06/display-gif-animation-in-wpf/

Comment: tried it, but it ruins the image quality. Any other solution or dll that we can directly use?